# Imbalanced data for regression task

Tags: machine-learning, regression, imbalanced-data

I have a question about regression task with imbalanced dataset.

Here is a histogramme of my target.

[image]

My target is a value between 0 and 1, but 54 % value is just 1.

Almost 70 % value is around 1.

So, when I design prediction model with this target value, the performance of my model is poor (tested with cross_val_score(cv=5), used model is randomforest regressor)

My idea is using mixed model (classification & Regression), but I'm not sure it can help because

dataset is imbalanced.

Could you give me an advice please ?

I tried to use different metrics like (RMSE, MAE, R2) but is it possible use different loss function ?

Comment: The notion of class imbalance does not apply to regression problems, only to classification ones. In any case, this is not a *programming* question, hence it is off-topic here - please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info